# Inserting values into new column based on a LEAD () function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called Sales and I created a column `sales_next`. I want to base each row's value in `sales_next` using a LEAD function. I got this so far, but I for some reason can't figure out how to update every row.

```
INSERT INTO superstore_sales$ (sales_next)  
VALUES
(
(SELECT TOP 1
    LEAD(sales, 1) OVER (
        ORDER BY sales
    ) AS sales_next
    FROM superstore_sales$
    WHERE sales_next IS NULL
    ))
```

I have tried removing the TOP 1 and I get the multiple values in subquery error, of course because I am unsure how to tell SQL to grab one value for each row using the LEAD function.

Comment: It is an objective of a project I am doing, but I agree, good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A derived table (or a CTE) is updatable, if I understand what you're trying to do this should work:

```
update t set sales_next = sn
from (
  select sales_next, Lead(sales, 1) OVER (ORDER BY sales) AS sn
  from superstore_sales$
  where sales_next IS null
)t;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. Could you possibly explain to me how this works? Why set the sales_next column to sn?

Comment: What I mean is, how is superstore_sales$ updated, even though the command updated a table named t? I checked and the correct column has been updated, just confused

Comment: Wait a second, you are creating a derived table called T, with a variable that you will be using to update superstore_sales$ with. Like a temp table. Got it.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. The values of the Sales column are now just identical to sales_next, when they need to be offset. The sales_next should be the value of the next row down of Sales.Sales sales_next
22.96 22.96
375.34 375.4575
177.2 177.225
197.97 197.97
854.94 858.24
124.11 124.2
14.4 14.4
575.968 577.764
10.368 10.368
49.12 49.12

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.Aaron was right, no need to create the column physically. I only need to do it query time. I figured out how both LEAD and LAG operate and the final code was simple:

```
SELECT "Order ID", "Customer Name", Sales,
LEAD(Sales) OVER(ORDER BY Sales) as next_sales
FROM superstore_sales$;
```

Thank you for your help:)